# Corrupted commit in the far futur

Tags: git, gitkraken

For an unknown reason, my git repository has a commit set into the far futur

```
commit 1b792e2b9e1a1bfefe92f6802f6dbe9112f750b2
Author: Red Acted <redacted@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 16 12:55:41 2242 +13033507

Fix failing tests with project

Added tests for IDC

diff --git a/features/funcional/case_study/case_study.feature 
b/features/funcional/case_study/case_study.feature
```

Unfortunately, it now looks like I am condemned to have it in the face for eternity.

[image]

Is there a way to filter it out of view in Gitkraken?

I am unsure about rewriting the history, because that will change all commit ids that are linked in another external system. But if I can fix the repository, I would try that as well.

Comment: It has a future date because whoever made it set the date into the future (this is easy to do: you can just set your computer's clock to lie to Git, or you can program Git to do the lying). To pseudo-rewrite the commit locally (without changing hash IDs) you can use `git replace`, but it's possible that GitKraken will use Git with replacements disabled, so that might not help. The *actual* commit will, as you noted, forever be set up like that. You can rewrite history using the same `git replace` followed by copying the repo to a new repo with `git filter-repo`.

Comment: This is very interesting, Thank you. However I confirm that as of June 20 2022, GitKraken ignores the replacement.